# Output buffering still outputting data

Tags: php, output-buffering

I have a simple enough code chunk:

```
ob_start();
include('api/emails/pmEmail.php');
$email = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

As I understand it, this should get the data in my file, parse it since it's an include, store it to $email, then end, all without outputting it to the browser.

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. The file, as the name suggests, contains an email template, outputs, and because its part of an API, breaks the return. I checked my ini file, and output_buffering is set to 4096, which seems like a reasonable value. I don't know if there is some other setting I need or what I'm doing wrong. This example exists a bunch of times on the web, I don't know if its because I'm outputting a full HTML file or something else.

Comment: What's the end goal? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please try commenting out the include statement, and instead put a simple echo. What happens then? Will the output be captured, or is it still sent to the browser?

Comment: The goal is to get the email content (after its parsed) into a variable to send with the PHP mail function. And when using an echo, I don't get an output. It seems clear its because of include, but this example is all over the net, so wasn't sure if I was screwing something up.

Comment: Check if there's an error in the included file. Try including a script that only does something trivial, like echoing something.

Comment: This feels like it would be better addressed by using a templating engine (e.g., Twig) and SwiftMailer. Those two combined give you a lot of power around emailing data in flexible and predictable ways.

Comment: I'll take a look at both of them, thanks! I actually found my problem, and it was my own stupidity, as is wont.

Answer (score 1):

Someone else pointed out this to me:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php#77223

There was an error in my include script that wasn't getting output. Putting that together helped me find the bug and resolve it.